# RabbitMQ Pika jumbled message body

Tags: python, json, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to create a simple file download and upload service with RabbitMQ in Python. I made Server and Client scripts and defined some objects that serialize and deserialize into and from json for the requests, so I could send a file uid or other parameters alongside the binary data (encoded with base64). Everything works when sending small files, but when I start sending bigger things (tested with a 1.4mb text file), I start getting JSONDecode errors. I am dumping the message sent and received to files, and it looks like the sent message is a correctly formatted json. However, the message received seems to be jumbled, for example:

Sending: {"uid":"test",Rhc2Rhc2Rhc2Rhc2Rhc2Rhc2=="}

Received: Rhc2Rhc2{"uid":"test",Rhc2Rhc2Rhc2Rhc2=="}

Obviously the jumbled blocks are much bigger than that. Has anyone run into this problem before?

Here are some code segments, I can upload the full code but it is not very tidy:

Upload Request:

```
class FileSystemUploadRequest:

def __init__(self, uid, data):
    self.uid = uid
    self.data = data

def encode(self):
    dicc = {"uid": self.uid, "data": base64.b64encode(self.data).decode()}
    return json.dumps(dicc)

@staticmethod
def decode(jsonstr):
    dicc = json.loads(jsonstr)
    uid = dicc["uid"]
    data = base64.b64decode(dicc["data"])
    return FileSystemUploadRequest(uid, data)
```

Client (sender):

```
def put_file_blocking(self, uid, data):

    print(" [x] Llamaron a put_file_blocking")

    corr_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    request = FileSystemUploadRequest(uid, data)

    f = open("dump", "w")
    f.write(request.encode())
    f.close()

    # Send upload request
    self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                               routing_key=self.queue_upload,
                               properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                   reply_to=self.callback_queue_name,
                                   correlation_id=corr_id
                               ),
                               body=request.encode())
```

Server (receiver):

```
def upload_request(ch, method, props, body):

f = open("_dump", "w")
f.write(body.decode())
f.close()

# Get Upload Request
request = FileSystemUploadRequest.decode(body)
print(" [x] Received upload request for: " + request.uid)
filename = fs_dir + "/" + request.uid

# Do upload
f = open(filename, "wb")
f.write(request.data)
f.close()

# Create Upload Response
status = Status.OK
response = FileSystemUploadResponse(status)

# Send response
ch.basic_publish(exchange='',
                 routing_key=props.reply_to,
                 properties=pika.BasicProperties(correlation_id=props.correlation_id),
                 body=response.encode())
ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

print(" [x] Finished upload request for: " + request.uid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RabbitMQ is a message broker and not a file storage system. As the assumption is messages are somewhat limited in size, several optimization are in place which will work against your use case.

To share files in a distributed system you should rely on an object storage of sort such as [OpenStack Swift](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/) or [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_ND&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=ACQ-P%7CPS-GO%7CBrand%7CDesktop%7CSU%7CStorage%7CS3%7CND%7CEN%7CText&sc_content=s3_e&sc_detail=aws%20s3&sc_category=Storage&sc_segment=293606560773&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=ND&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!293606560773!e!!g!!aws%20s3&ef_id=Cj0KCQiA1sriBRD-ARIsABYdwwFL1wIDDqk2ceA464iaLhidpsrbpv45l-wQVSFWF-ISrneYsxqscd0aAjn-EALw_wcB:G:s).

You can still use RabbitMQ to notify the presence of a new file but rather than embedding it into the message, you provide the location in your object storage and the consumer retrieves the file from there.

A couple of reference links:

[RabbitMQ best practices](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2017-12-29-part1-rabbitmq-best-practice.html)

[Can RabbitMQ handle big messages?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-discuss/ZYsqJt422cQ)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the links! I was actually going to use RabbitMQ to mock a service like AWS S3 for testing before moving there and dealing with quotas. What threw me off was that I had previously done something like this with RabbitMQ on Java and had no problems, so I thought it had to do with pika. But I might just not have tried a really large file.

Comment: Technically it should be possible and there are examples out there on how to send files through RabbitMQ. Yet, as it's far from an ideal solution, I'd recommend to use something else to mock AWS S3 like for example [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) or [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto).